# How to make {$DEFINE xxx} visible to other units in FreePascal?

Tags: freepascal

I made a PlatformDetection.pas source file with some `DEFINE` to detect the platform:

```
{$IF DEFINED(CPUARM)}
  {$DEFINE ARM}
{$ELSE}
  {$IF DEFINED(i386) or DEFINED(cpui386) or DEFINED(cpux86_64)}
    {$DEFINE INTEL}
  {$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF INTEL}
  // Code here is compile, as expected with my processor
{$ENDIF}
```

This "seems" to work in functions inside that file. However, when used in other units, those symbols seems not defined:

```
uses PlatformDetection;

...

{$IFDEF INTEL}
   // Code here not compiled, even through this same line work when used inside PlatformDetection.pas.
{$ENDIF}
```

My question is: **How to make `DEFINE` symbols visible in other units?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{$DEFINE}` symbols are not visible across unit boundaries.  Only symbols that are defined globally in the project settings, or via the command-line `-d` option, are visible across unit bounaries.

But, what you can do instead is put the `{$DEFINE}` directives in a `.inc` file, and then use a `{$I}` directive in any unit that needs to see the symbols, eg:

`PlatformDetection.inc`:

```pascal
{$IF DEFINED(CPUARM)}
  {$DEFINE ARM}
{$ELSE}
  {$IF DEFINED(i386) or DEFINED(cpui386) or DEFINED(cpux86_64)}
    {$DEFINE INTEL}
  {$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}
```

`SomeUnit.pas`:

```
{$I 'PlatformDetection.inc'}

...

{$IFDEF INTEL}
  // Code here is compiled, as expected with my processor
{$ENDIF}
```